# How much faster is the "15-inch 2.6 GHz Retina Display MacBook Pro" when developing Rails Apps?

Tags: macbook-pro, rails

I'm specially interested in how faster would it make the processing of Asset Pipelines (Sprockets).

I currently have a first generation Unibody MacBook, and it feels really slow...

Comment: Since few people are likely to have your exact current laptop, use it for Rails development, and want to know how much faster the specific model you're interested in will be, I'm closing this as too localized. Additionally, we would need more information about your current computer to help you. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a page with benchmarks on a large collection of Mac computers. Apart from this, there is no objective way to answer your question.

http://browser.primatelabs.com/mac-benchmarks